# How to correctly use intermediate files in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Consider the following scenario:

```
tempfile: bar
    generate tempfile (using bar)

foo: tempfile
    generate foo (using bar)
```

Now, when running `make foo`, I only want `foo` to be built when `bar` is changed. What actually happens is that Make removes the tempfile (which I don't mind by itself), and then it builds foo every single time, even though `bar` has not changed.

Any advice?

Comment: Either I misunderstand what you claim is happening, or your claim is false. Make doesn't remove files nilly willy. Example output from such run might prove which it is.

Comment: Oh you bet it does. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517190/what-causes-make-to-delete-intermediate-files

Comment: Nobody's saying that `make` will *never* remove intermediate files.  But it's not clear (to me at least) why `tempfile` would be removed in the example you've shown.  Please provide a real example along with all output etc.

Comment: Ok. Anyhoo, the "builds foo even though bar has not changed" doesn't seem right to me. Perhaps doing the build with `--debug[=options]` (try different options) might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: If `make` really deletes `tempfile` then your real `Makefile` is not what you show, or you declared `tempfile` as an intermediate (with the `.INTERMEDIATE` special target). Please edit your question and create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that we can reproduce your problem.